# Arduino, can't seem to get syntax correct

Tags: c, arduino

The water temp should stay between 24-27'c - if not prints to the LCD and sounds the buzzer. The water level is monitored also and should illuminate the relevant LEDs.

My issue is when compiling this code from the loop I always get an error. I would assume i'm missing curly brackets or something fairly basic, but I can't for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. - I accept this is likely to be a simple fix but I cant see the wood for the trees.

```
        void loop()
        {

            WaterTemp = (sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));

            Serial.print(F(" Requesting temperatures..."));
            sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperature
            Serial.println("DONE");

            Serial.print(F("Water Temperature is: "));
            Serial.println(WaterTemp);
            lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
            lcd.print(WaterTemp, 1);
            lcd.print(F(" "));
            lcd.print((char)223);
            lcd.print(F("C"));
            delay(1000);

        }

        if (WaterTemp <24)
        {
            tone(piezoPin,600, 200);
            delay(1000);
            lcd.print("TEMP LOW");
        }
        if (WaterTemp >27)
        {
            tone(piezoPin, 400, 200);
            delay(1000);
            lcd.print("TEMP HIGH");
        }
    }

    value = analogRead(read); //Read data from analog pin and store

    if (value<=390) {
        Serial.println("Water level: 0mm -Fill FISHTANK NOW!!!");
        digitalWrite (4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (3, LOW);
        digitalWrite (2, LOW);
        tone(piezoPin,500, 400);
        delay(1500);
    }
    else if (value>450 && value<=529) {
        Serial.println("Water level: 10mm Fill Fishtank ASAP");
        digitalWrite (4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (2, LOW);
    }
    else if (value>540 && value<=550) {
        Serial.println("Water level: 20mm Fishtank getting low!!");
        digitalWrite (4, LOW);
        digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (2, LOW);
    }
    else if (value>560 && value<=570) {
        Serial.println("Water level:30mm  Fishtank below optimum level");
        digitalWrite (4, LOW);
        digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite (2, HIGH);
    }

    else if (value>580) {
        Serial.println("Water level:40mm Fishtank FULL");
        digitalWrite (4, LOW);
        digitalWrite (3, LOW);
        digitalWrite (2, HIGH);

    }

    delay(2000); // Check for new value every 3 sec
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the actual error

Comment: Most of your code is _outside_ the loop function

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. If the code you posted is what you are trying to compile, then it will not compile because you are missing definitions and declarations, and you need to insert them or include headers.

Comment: The curly bracket after `delay(1000);` is probably the problem, remove it. and probably the one before `value = analogRead(read);`, too

Comment: @bazmanuk notice the loop closing after `delay(1000);`? That might be your issue

Comment: One hint, indent your code properly for all blocks. Most likely you would have seen it yourself already.

Comment: Thanks for such speedy replies everyone I removed the { as suggested and it works!.  On a totally separate note it seems with a water level sensor an lcd and a temp probe and piezo connected, my uno is unable to supply power to the lcds which make up part of my system is there a way around this? or do I need to buy an additional breadboard power supply?

Answer (score 1):

You have a '{' after the delay statement that shouldn't be there. With it there, it makes all the code outside of it not be in the loop function, which would cause the compiler error.